# Accepting a Message Before Writing One

Tags: networking, go, tcp, chat

I have a server that listens to 2 ports and transfers messages between the 2 ports.  The only problem is that each client (or each port) has to submit a message before they can receive the previous message that the other port sent.  For example, if client 1 says "hello", client 2 will not receive the message unless he sends a message first.

I want to find a way to make it so that each client will have to receive the previous message before being able to send a new one.  (Since Client 1 will not have anything to receive until Client 2 says something, I am planning to send it a string that has placeholder text.)

Can anyone help me with how to go about this?  I try putting my listening code and my code for writing a message for each client into their own go routines, but that did not do the job.  Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

## Server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

var message string = "Client 2 is receiving your message"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("The server is listening on Port 3000 and 8080")
    //Set up listeners for the ports each client is using
    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:3000")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) 
    }
    listener2, err := net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go acceptLoop(listener)
    acceptLoop(listener2)  // run in the main goroutine
}

func acceptLoop(l net.Listener) {
    defer l.Close()
    for {
            c, err := l.Accept()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println("New connection found!")
            go listenConnection(c)
    }
}

func listenConnection(conn net.Conn) {
        fmt.Println("Yay")
        for {
                buffer := make([]byte, 1400)
                dataSize, err := conn.Read(buffer)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("Connection has closed")
                    return
                }

                //This is the message you received
                data := buffer[:dataSize]
                fmt.Print("Received message: ", string(data))

                // Send the message back
                _, err = conn.Write([]byte(message))
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatalln(err)
                }
                fmt.Print("Message sent: ", string(data))
                message = string(data)
        }
}
```

## Client 1

```
    package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net"
        "bufio"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:3000")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }

for {
        reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
        fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(text))
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        for {
                buffer := make([]byte, 1400)
                dataSize, err := conn.Read(buffer)
                if err != nil {
                        fmt.Println("The connection has closed!")
                        return
                }

                data := buffer[:dataSize]
                fmt.Println("Received message: ", string(data))
                break
        }

    }
}
```

My second client is the same as my first except "localhost:3000" is replaced with "localhost:8080".

I will appreciate any help!  I'm fairly new to networking and Go, so any tips will be great.

Answer (score 0):

Right now your `Server` is just an echo. It responds with the message received from the client.

If you want to relay the message between two clients, the first thing you need to figure out is what should happen if 3 clients connect (2 to the first port, 1 to the other)?

If you expect to have just one client connected to each port you could do something like this (**pseudo**-go-code):

```
func main() {
  // ...
  # Channels must be buffered or else clients will deadlock.
  relay := make(chan string, 1)
  go acceptLoop(listener1, relay)
  acceptLoop(listener2, relay)
}

func acceptLoop(l, relay) {
  for {
    conn := l.Accept()
    for {
       relay <- conn.Read()
       conn.Write(<-relay)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would I still need my listenConnection() function if I used channels?  And would I need to change my client programs at all?

Comment: You don't need `listenConnection` if you handle exactly one client per listener at a time. The client is fine, assuming you are aware that TCP is a streaming protocol and non-delimited Read/Write protocol only works for short messages with significant delay between them.

Comment: So I need to make a string channel.  Then, I need to modify acceptLoop() to take a string channel in addition to the listener.  AcceptLoop will then listen to connections and pass the strings back and forth.  Is this correct?  On another note, I think the string channel may need to be a []byte channel instead as this is how the channels send messages.

Comment: I meant that is how the connections send messages.

Comment: You can certainly pass `[]byte` via channel. You should think of the `acceptLoop` as a client handler: it waits for a client connection, then it handles the connection by reading, relaying (via channel) and writing back.

Comment: I'm having a problem when I try to compile. I get some errors on the "relay <- conn.Read()" line.  They says "not enough arguments in call to conn.Read" and "multiple-value conn.Read() in single-value context".  Would you happen to know what could be going on here?  Thank you very much for your help by the way.  I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: As I said, this is pseudo-code. Youl'll have to make sure to declare types, pass proper arguments and allocate all the supporting variables.